# Vector valued 2-forms which satisfy Jacobi Identity

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-algebras, tensors

Motivated by this [MO  question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/209694/differential-and-pre-differential-of-jacobi-identity) we ask the following two questions:

1)What is  an example of  a compact manifold $M$ which does not admit any   smooth (1,2) tensor $\omega$ which restriction to each fibre(tangent space) gives  a simple Lie algebra?

2)What is  an example of  a compact manifold $M$ which  admit  at least one  smooth (1,2) tensor $\omega$ which restriction to each fibre(tangent space) gives  a simple Lie algebra?

Comment: My understanding is that there are, up to isomorphism, precisely two 2-dim Lie algebras: the abelian one and one with $[x,y] = x$.  But neither is simple.  So it seems as though any surface gives an example of 1).  That said, you mention in the linked MO question that every parallelizable manifold has the "tensorial property", so perhaps I'm missing something...

Comment: @JasonDeVito  Thanks for your  comment. According to your comment I realize that I should add "n>2" in this  and  MO question. is this what you mean?

Comment: Well, perhaps that is what I mean :-).  On a related note, I don't think there are any simple Lie algebras in dimension 4,5,6, 7, 9, 11, ..., so there should be plenty of examples of 1) in these dimensions.  On the other hand, every orientable three manifold is parallelizable, so these are all examples of 2).

Comment: @JasonDeVito Thanks for your information on dimension 4,5,6..